# Sort list by decreasing length of the strings

Tags: list, sorting

I have this list:

```
(setq MYLIST '("J. Phys."
               "New. J. Phys." 
               "J. Phys. Soc. Jap."
               "Phys. Plasmas"))
```

How can I get a new list ordered by the decreasing length of the strings? :

```
("J. Phys. Soc. Jap."
 "New. J. Phys."
 "Phys. Plasmas"
 "J. Phys.")
```

**ADDENDUM.** It happens that when I try the [DoMiNeLa10](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/12563/dominela10) answer on a 232 element list I get a 130 list. **102 of them goes lost** (they are not duplicates). If you need my list as a file please tell me how can I share it.

You can find my list here: [MYLIST](https://pastebin.com/3u2vf34f).

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 's answer is correct, you need to use the result of the function: `(setq MYLIST (my-sort-decreasing-length MYLIST))` - without this a reference to the original list may loose elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [DoMiNeLa10's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38902/15748) for the canonical answer.

On Emacs 25 and later, however, and if you don't care about sheer performance, there is a way to save yourself some typing:

```el
(require 'seq)
(seq-sort-by #'length #'> MYLIST)
```

or

```
(seq-sort-by #'string-width #'> MYLIST)
```

should you care about displaying the strings.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: (downvote not mine). Can you please take a look my edited part of the question?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Have you tried using `copy-sequence` as I mention in [my comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38897/sort-list-by-decreasing-length-of-the-strings/38903?noredirect=1#comment61374_38902) to DoMiNeLa10's answer? I.e. like so: https://pastebin.com/raw/70G6CeRG

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Otherwise, try using my suggestion which automatically does this for you.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi If either of these suggestions fix the issue, then you should consider reaccepting DoMiNeLa10's answer with the `copy-sequence` caveat.

Comment: The `seq-sort-by` solution works fine. I tried with `copy-sequence` and the DoMiNeLA10's solution by I've not been able to make it work.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Glad it works, but it's *very* strange that using `copy-sequence` doesn't make DoMiNeLa10's solution work. Are you sure you re-evaluated the function after adding `copy-sequence`?

Comment: Once again, you're right. I didn't understand the behaviour of (copy-sequence). Now it works. It think I should reaccept the DoMiNeLa10 answer... but it needs to be updated with you caveat, otherwise it doesn't work (at least in my case).

Answer (score 5):

You can write a function which uses `sort` and pass it a predicate that compares lengths:

```el
(defun my-sort-decreasing-length (list)
  (sort list
        (lambda (a b)
          (> (length a) (length b)))))
```

---

Note that the result of this function must be used as the new list.

```el
(setq some-list (my-sort-decreasing-length some-list))
```

Comment: Note that `sort` destructively modifies the `list`, so you should usually pass it through `copy-sequence` first.

Comment: What @Basil said. And if you are OK with the list-structure modification and you have a variable that points to the original list, and you want it to also point to the modified list, then you need to _assign it to the result_ of using `sort`: `(setq mylist (my-sort mylist))`.

Comment: I cannot accept your answer because of an issue with long lists. Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: Suggest to mark this as the correct answer. Updated it to avoid confusion.